# How to perform a function for at least 3 seconds or more

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a template for wordpress , and I would like to insert a picture while the page is loading , but I want the load to last at least 3 seconds , you can assign a minimum time of execution of a function ? in this case i use the $ ( window ) .load ( ) and i add a class to a div placed inside the page to show it.
it works but i want the loadig image to be show for 3 seconds and after the window load event i want to remove the class that i added to sho the div, this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="loader">
    loading image   
</div>

<div class="content">
    main content
</div>


<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">         </script><!-- jQuery -->



</body>
</html>
```

this is my css

```
.loader{`enter code here`
    position: fixed;`enter code here`
    top: 0;
    bottom:0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 999;
    display: none;
}

.show-loader{
    display: block;
}

.content{
    background-color: red;
    height: 600px;
}
```

rhis is my JQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.loader').addClass('show-loader');
    });
    $('.loader').removeClass('show-loader');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple put your Javascript into a function that will be called after 3 Seconds / 3000 Miliseconds.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.loader').addClass('show-loader');
  });

  setTimeout(loadImage, 3000);
}

function loadImage(){ 

  $('.loader').removeClass('show-loader');
  });
```

Comment: What if jQuery(document).ready event is been fired before the setTimeout ?

Comment: i have just corrected my error ;) i havent read the last part of the question "remove after 3 seconds"

Answer (score 3):

You can use a timer with `setTimeout()` to trigger an event some specific amount of time in the future.  It isn't clear to me exactly what you're trying to do, but if you just want to remove the class 3 seconds after you applied it, you can do this:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery('.loader').addClass('show-loader');
    // remove the class, three seconds later
    setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('.loader').removeClass('show-loader');
    }, 3000);
});
```

FYI, I removed the `jQuery(document).ready()` part of the code because I can't see any reason that it is needed.  The `jQuery(window).load()` event always come after the `.ready()` event and `window` is always available.

Comment: How about keeping loaders display block in css and just hiding it after window onload or after onload timeout ?

Comment: @RayonDabre - the OP can use either classes that work with style sheets or direct css manipulation.  Either will work just fine.

Comment: I would show the image defUlt and hide the div default after the page loaded hide the image and show the div

Comment: @mplungjan - that may be a good way to do it - I couldn't really tell from the OP's question exactly what the use case was so I just stuck with the model they presented.